# Compiler doesn't find methods of class Files

Tags: java, compiler-errors

so I am supposed to write a small program to write the reversed alphabet in a file, but for some reason the compiler does not recognize any of the methods of the Files-Class.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;

 class Exercise {
    Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\schuele\\Documents\\GitProjects\\3hit-Grual\\RandomAccess\\Alphabet.txt");
    byte[] data;
    ByteBuffer out;

   if(Files.exists(file)){

    }
}
```

The strange thing is though, that the compiler can find the class Files just not its methods.

When compiled I get this message:

```
Error:(17, 4) java: illegal start of type
Error:(17, 19) java: <identifier> expected
Error:(17, 20) java: ';' expected
Error:(17, 21) java: illegal start of type
Error:(17, 22) java: <identifier> expected
Error:(17, 23) java: ';' expected
```

The errors all happen in line 17, which is the line the `Files` class is used.

Comment: What is your line 17?

Comment: This is not a valid java code. The if statement code won't get copied into constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place code like that directly under a `class`' definition. You need to put it in a method, constructor or anonymous initialization block. E.g.:

```
class Exercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // Here!

        Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\schuele\\Documents\\GitProjects\\3hit-Grual\\RandomAccess\\Alphabet.txt");
        byte[] data;
        ByteBuffer out;

        if (Files.exists(file)) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you write your if block outside of a method. Please add a method or a constructor.